# watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#10 stuck for 23s! [Kworker/10:2:10578]

Tags: cpu, lockup

I just installed ubuntu 18.10 alngside windows 10. After the instalation completed and restarted this appeared on my screen.
I am lvl 1 ubuntu user XD
Thought someone here can help.
Thanks!